# Speed up PostgreSQL query in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm running a query against a large PSQL database in order to do a bit of parsing on the results, but I'm having a problem with the speed of it. The selection query is as follows:

```
SELECT cycle_id, description FROM cycle, term WHERE cycle_id =           
  term_id AND cycle.date IS NULL                               

UNION ALL 
  SELECT cycle_id, description FROM cycle, sect WHERE cycle_id =           
  sect_id AND cycle.date IS NULL

UNION ALL
  SELECT cycle_id, description FROM cycle, quart WHERE cycle_id =           
  quart_id AND cycle.date IS NULL
```

The ResultSet contains ~25 million rows, which with the default psql fetch size overflows the java heap space.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out the optimal fetch size for this query (my heap space has 119 MB available) and any other optimizations that can cut down the runtime for this selection. I've tried using limit/offset to select bits of data at a time, but to no avail, and the program takes far too long to run. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked which part of the program is running slowly? (query or processing results) What kind of performance you are expecting?

Comment: Changing the fetch size only works if you turn off autocommit: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor for general performance questions please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions